# mathematical calculation on pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have converted one excel sheet into a pivot table using pandas data frame. I want to do some calculations. The pivot table created is as below. The first line is the header. 
I would like to calculate the yield for each Item like for example Badam = T/HA (i.e) Yield for `Badam = 14558/4811` and add Yield as my final column.
T and HA are from the "Unit" column. 
I couldn't find any examples to proceed further also. It would be great if experts help.

[image]

Or Should I move away from pivot table to "groupby" for this kind of calculations? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post a reproducible example of your data frame ? And the computation you want to achieve is always T/HA for each item ?

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe not copy a image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example data:

```
    state   District    Year    Item    Unit    Amount
0   TN      Trichy      2016    Badam   HA  4811
1   TN      Trichy      2016    Badam   N   59
2   TN      Trichy      2016    Badam   T   14558
3   TN      Trichy      2016    Carrots HA  18973
4   TN      Trichy      2016    Carrots N   123
5   TN      Trichy      2016    Carrots T   35990
```

here is the code:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index=['state','District','Year','Item'], values = 'Amount', columns =['Unit'])

    Out[25]: 
                        Unit       HA    N      T
    state District Year Item                      
    TN    Trichy   2016 Badam     4811   59  14558
                        Carrots  18973  123  35990

res.assign(result = res['T']/res['HA'])

    Out[28]: 
                        Unit        HA    N      T    result
    state District Year Item                                
    TN    Trichy   2016 Badam     4811   59  14558  3.025982
                        Carrots  18973  123  35990  1.896906
```

Comment: Thank yo so much Alexey and really appreciate your valuable time. Am still a beginner. Am bit confused on how to unpivot this table. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, I want to convert this into csv  with State, district, year, Item, Unit, Amount and yield columns. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to save it in csv, you should use something like this: res.to_csv('res.csv').  If you have some problems with multiindex when you write it to csv, you can reset index and then write dataframe to csv. Something like this: res.reset_index()  res.to_csv('res.csv'). Does it help?

Comment: Yes, Thanks Alexey. when I try res.reset_index(), all the columns except the newly calculated "results" columns  are available in the excel sheet. AM not sure why "results" column is not part of dataframe. I tried res.info(). This doesn't show "results" column.

Comment: Alexey, Thanks for all your time and help. I could write all the columns to excel when I converted to `res['results'] = res['T'] / res['HA']`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I tried as Alexey mentioned and calculated the results. I Tried converting pivot table to excel sheet using (to_excel). But only the last 4 columns are being written into excel sheet (i.e) "HA, N, T and results" but not state, District, Year and Item. How to write all 8 columns into excel sheet?

Next thing I tried was res.stack(). This is pandas series and then converted them into dataframe and then writing to excel sheet. This is also writing all the columns into one single tall column in the excel file. Does that mean pivot table is getting lost when I try to calculate by using `res.assign(result = res['T']/res['HA'])`?
Can someone throw light on how to unpivot this table as

```
   state District Year Item      HA     N   T      results           
   TN    Trichy   2016 Badam     4811   59  14558  3.025982
   TN    Trichy   2016 Carrots  18973  123  35990  1.896906
```

Thanks.